# Refresh cell before printing

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to find a way to refresh the calculation of a specific cell before the printing because sometimes the value is incorrect until the sheet is recalculated.

I tried with:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean) 
 For Each wk in Worksheets 
 wk.Calculate 
 Next 
End Sub
```

But I think this doesn't work anymore on the latest Excel versions or maybe I don't how to use it.

Comment: What is wrong with just doing Application.Calculate ?

Comment: Is possible to run that macros automatically just before the user clicks on File->Print or uses the crtl+P shortcut? Or is mandatory to print via vba code too just to get the calculation/refresh done?